Table is created using render_datatable with dynamic data from MySQLdatabase but there is no method in the controller or model for fetching the data
In the render_datatable function, when I change the second parameter from 'leads' to 'lead', the table appears blank even though there is data.
I don't understand where the data from the database is being fetched.
There is no method in the controller or model for fetching the data and also AJAX is not being used to fetch the data here.
Is there another way to fetch data from the MySQL database?
````<?php defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
<?php init_head(); ?>
<div id="wrapper">
   <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel_s">
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <?php
                     $table_data = array();
                     $_table_data = array(
                        '<span class="hide"> - </span><div class="checkbox mass_select_all_wrap"><input type="checkbox" id="mass_select_all" data-to-table="leads"><label></label></div>',
                        array(
                        'name'=>_l('the_number_sign'),
                        'th_attrs'=>array('class'=>'toggleable', 'id'=>'th-number')
                        ),
                        array(
                        'name'=>_l('leads_dt_name'),
                        'th_attrs'=>array('class'=>'toggleable', 'id'=>'th-name')
                        ),
                     );
                     if(is_gdpr() && get_option('gdpr_enable_consent_for_leads') == '1') {
                        $_table_data[] = array(
                           'name'=>_l('gdpr_consent') .' ('._l('gdpr_short').')',
                           'th_attrs'=>array('id'=>'th-consent', 'class'=>'not-export')
                        );
                     }
                     $_table_data[] = array(
                        'name'=>_l('lead_company'),
                        'th_attrs'=>array('class'=>'toggleable', 'id'=>'th-company')
                     );
                     $_table_data[] =   array(
                        'name'=>_l('leads_dt_email'),
                        'th_attrs'=>array('class'=>'toggleable', 'id'=>'th-email')
                     );
                     $_table_data[] =  array(
                        'name'=>_l('leads_dt_phonenumber'),
                        'th_attrs'=>array('class'=>'toggleable', 'id'=>'th-phone')
                     );
                     $_table_data[] =  array(
                        'name'=>_l('leads_dt_lead_value'),
                        'th_attrs'=>array('class'=>'toggleable', 'id'=>'th-lead-value')
                        );
                     $_table_data[] =  array(
                        'name'=>_l('tags'),
                        'th_attrs'=>array('class'=>'toggleable', 'id'=>'th-tags')
                     );
                     $_table_data[] = array(
                        'name'=>_l('leads_dt_assigned'),
                        'th_attrs'=>array('class'=>'toggleable', 'id'=>'th-assigned')
                     );
                     $_table_data[] = array(
                        'name'=>_l('leads_dt_status'),
                        'th_attrs'=>array('class'=>'toggleable', 'id'=>'th-status')
                     );
                     $_table_data[] = array(
                        'name'=>_l('leads_source'),
                        'th_attrs'=>array('class'=>'toggleable', 'id'=>'th-source')
                     );
                     $_table_data[] = array(
                        'name'=>_l('leads_dt_last_contact'),
                        'th_attrs'=>array('class'=>'toggleable', 'id'=>'th-last-contact')
                     );
                     $_table_data[] = array(
                        'name'=>_l('leads_dt_datecreated'),
                        'th_attrs'=>array('class'=>'date-created toggleable','id'=>'th-date-created')
                     );
                     foreach($_table_data as $_t){
                        array_push($table_data,$_t);
                     }
                     $custom_fields = get_custom_fields('leads',array('show_on_table'=>1));
                     foreach($custom_fields as $field){
                     array_push($table_data,$field['name']);
                     }
                     $table_data = hooks()->apply_filters('leads_table_columns', $table_data);
                # This function call appears to be misbehaving:
                     render_datatable($table_data,'leads',
                     array('customizable-table'),
                     array(
                        'id'=>'table-leads',
                        'data-last-order-identifier'=>'leads',
                        'data-default-order'=>get_table_last_order('leads'),
                        )); ?>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<?php init_tail(); ?>
</body>
</html>

When I try to add two more columns to the same table, which already exist in the leads table, the table goes blank again. It seems like the second parameter of the render_datatable function leads is already defined with a limited number of columns.
Here is the render_datatable function for creating a table.
function render_datatable($headings = [], $class = '', $additional_classes = [''], $table_attributes = [])
{
    $_additional_classes = '';
    $_table_attributes   = ' ';
    if (count($additional_classes) > 0) {
        $_additional_classes = ' ' . implode(' ', $additional_classes);
    }
    $CI      = & get_instance();
    $browser = $CI->agent->browser();
    $IEfix   = '';
    if ($browser == 'Internet Explorer') {
        $IEfix = 'ie-dt-fix';
    }

    foreach ($table_attributes as $key => $val) {
        $_table_attributes .= $key . '=' . '"' . $val . '" ';
    }

    $table = '<div class="' . $IEfix . '"><table' . $_table_attributes . 'class="dt-table-loading table table-' . $class . '' . $_additional_classes . '">';
    $table .= '<thead>';
    $table .= '<tr>';
    foreach ($headings as $heading) {
        if (!is_array($heading)) {
            $table .= '<th>' . $heading . '</th>';
        } else {
            $th_attrs = '';
            if (isset($heading['th_attrs'])) {
                foreach ($heading['th_attrs'] as $key => $val) {
                    $th_attrs .= $key . '=' . '"' . $val . '" ';
                }
            }
            $th_attrs = ($th_attrs != '' ? ' ' . $th_attrs : $th_attrs);
            $table .= '<th' . $th_attrs . '>' . $heading['name'] . '</th>';
        }
    }
    $table .= '</tr>';
    $table .= '</thead>';
    $table .= '<tbody></tbody>';
    $table .= '</table></div>';
    echo $table;
}```


Does this log any errors when it renders blank?

Thank you for your reply J Stach. I just wanted to let you know that my query has been resolved.

@RakeshKanaujiya: concerning your comment "my query has been resolved": you are welcome to self-answer your question. See
Can I answer my own question
